# Where to create JSON files on Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I have just created a simple web application using visual studio 2017. I'm trying to figure out where do I create the Json files that I need, there are a lot of JSON files on the solution explorer but I'm not sure whether they are the ones that I need. I'm new to visual studio. Please help.

[image]

Here are the codes that I have for site.js

[image]

Comment: You can create files by right clicking your project and selecting "Add => new item", but I have no idea what you need. You question is unclear to me and I suppose many others. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: yes, I was trying out some JSON activities on this youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw&t=961s) and he was using an external JSON file and using a URL to call them. I would like to do the same but on the local machine using visual studio.

Comment: I'm afraid nobody is going to watch that video to answer your question. I'm not sure what you mean by "using a URL to call them". Maybe he had a REST service? The point is, your question is very unclear and hard to answer. You might get better results, if you specify what you want to do, maybe in more technical terms (did the video explain the terms maybe?).

Comment: I have edited my post. It does work, I was able to get the JSON files and have them on the console but I would like to have the JSON file locally.